# PriorityQueue add Element will change the element, weird bug

Tags: java, addition, priority-queue

```
public class Main {    
public static class EE implements Comparable<EE> {
        int x;
        int[] rac;
        public  EE(int x, int[] rac) {
            this.x = x;
            this.rac = rac;
        }

        public int compareTo(EE that) {
            if (this.x != that.x) return this.x - that.x;
            else return this.rac[2] = that.rac[2];
        }
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [][] ary = {
                {1,1,3,3},

                {1,3,2,4},
                {2,3,3,4}};
        PriorityQueue<EE> pq = new PriorityQueue<EE>();
        for (int[] rec : ary) {
            EE e1 = new EE(rec[0], rec);
            EE e2 = new EE(rec[2], rec);
            pq.add(e1);
            pq.add(e2);
        }
    }
```

This piece of code I'm running, everything is fine but when the second for loop is entered, rec is [1, 3, 2, 4] initially, when pq.add(e1) get called, value of rec will become [1, 3, 3, 4] anyone can explain why this happens? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preoblem is in comapreTo method:

```
return this.rac[2] = that.rac[2];
```

It's returning always the latter `that.rac[2]`. It should be:

```
return this.rac[2] == that.rac[2];
```

Comment: It works! Will accept this answer after I'm allowed, but any idea why this will change the value of the element got added?

Comment: What you had was a condensed assignment. Basically your statement was assigning this.rac[2] = that.rac[2] and then returning this.rac[2]. It did both at the same time, hence the value changing. You needed to use == as a comparison operator, which does not perform assignment.